# sum of integer subset of an array, getting all results instead of first one

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, sum, powerset

my problem is quite unique. i am recursively finding powerset of an integer array, after that i am finding the sum of the array, if the sum is a certain number N i look for, it should print the array and stop executing, however, in my case it prints out all the subsets that equal to that N instead of just the first one.

snippet:

```
void main()
{
    char a;
    int arr[] = { 1, 4, 15, 20, 1, 1, 2, 3, 66, 14, 33 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int temp[12];
    powerSet(arr, temp, n, 0, 0);

    scanf("%c", &a);
}
void powerSet(int* arr, int* p, int n, int pos, int index)
{
    if (index >= n)
    {
        return;
    }
    p[pos] = arr[index];
    if (arrSum(0, pos, p, 0) == 100)
    {
        PrintRec(0, pos, p);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        //Most likely an issue here.
        powerSet(arr, p, n, pos + 1, index + 1);
        powerSet(arr, p, n, pos, index+1);
    }
}
void PrintRec(int j, int end, int* p)
{
    if (j > end)
    {
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("%d ", p[j]);
    PrintRec(j + 1, end, p);
}
```

arrSum:

```
int arrSum(int j, int end, int* p, int sum)
{
    if (j > end)
    {
        return sum;
    }
    arrSum(j + 1, end, p, sum +=p[j]);
}
```

The results i get are correct, but i only want the first result.

Comment: I think  you are missing `arrSum()`.

Comment: Can you show the `arrSum` code? The line `if (arrSum(0, pos, p, 0) == 100)` seems suspicious to me since from the posted code you are calling it with an uninitialized 12 element array where you have only explicitly set the value at location `pos`

Comment: The proper declarations for `main` are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char **argv)` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char *argv[]`). **note:** `main` is a function of `type int` and it returns a value. See: [C11 Standard §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup p1 (draft n1570)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). See also: [See What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Comment: i posted arrSum function, sorry about the confusion, and once again the entire solution is correct, i get valid arrays that their sum is equal to 0, but i only want the first one. @pstrjds

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin nothing much i can do about it, as that's how my professor instructed me to do.

Comment: Are you allowed to change the function declaration of the `powerSet` function, i.e. change the return type or the function arguments?

Comment: @user3386109 yes, that is allowed.

Comment: @TravisScott - if you are not on some strange embedded system, then print a copy of the [C11 Standard §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup p1 (draft n1570)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1) take it to him (or her) and ask why? If they can't answer, drop the class (you still have time) and re-enroll with another professor.

Comment: while the returned type from `main(()` is always `int`.  There are some (WAY BEHIND) compilers, like Visual Studio, that will accept invalid code without outputting a message complaining about the return type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force the recursion to end early, you can have the `powerSet` function return a boolean that indicates that the task is completed. After `PrintRec` is called, `powerSet` should return `true`, and if any recursive call returns `true`, then the caller should immediately return `true`. That will prevent any additional calls to `powerSet` and will force the recursion stack to unwind.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool powerSet(int* arr, int* p, int n, int pos, int index)
{
    if (index >= n)
    {
        return false;
    }
    p[pos] = arr[index];
    if (arrSum(0, pos, p, 0) == 100)
    {
        PrintRec(0, pos, p);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (powerSet(arr, p, n, pos + 1, index + 1))
            return true;
        if (powerSet(arr, p, n, pos, index+1))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note: if you aren't allowed to use `<stdbool.h>`, then replace `bool` with `int`, replace `true` with `1`, and replace `false` with `0`.

Comment: Splendid! that worked perfectly, thank you very much.
I used int instead of bool.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the call stack is full of `powerset`-function executions that will all be brought to an end, each having the chance to enter `print` without the chance to detect that it has been called before.

You could introduce a "shared counter" that is incremented once `print` is called. Share this counter by, for example, passing it by reference to all the calls:

```
int main() {
    int printCounter=0;
    powerSet(...., &printCounter);
}

void powerSet(int* arr, int* p, int n, int pos, int index, int *counter) {
   ...
   if(!*counter) {  // this block avoids that print will be called more than once
      print(...);
      (*counter)++;
   }
   ...
   powerSet(...., counter);
```

Comment: This solution would probably work, but is there a more elegant way to solve the problem? or is it the fact that my function is built the way it is?

Comment: Also, i have just been informed i can't do that.